# Cannot import android.support.v7.media

Tags: android, import

I need to import this to be able to use MediaRouterSelector.

I already updated my Android Support Repository in SDK Manage, but I still can't import this library :/

I want to follow this tutorial:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter.html

So I can add screenshare to my app and connect to my SmartTV.

Answer (score 2):

You've updated Android Support Repository through SDK Manager.

Now you need to import required artifact in your project.

1. Open the `build.gradle` file for your application.
2. Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example:

   ```
   allprojects {
      repositories {
         jcenter()
         maven {
             url "https://maven.google.com"
         }
      }
   }
   ```
3. Add the support library to the dependencies section. For example, to add the v4 core-utils library, add the following lines:

   ```
   dependencies {
        ...
        compile "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1"
   }
   ```

Take a [look](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html), how you should integrate in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Update to 
Android SDK 25
Android Build Tools v25.0.3
Android Support Repository

Add the dependency 
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1'

Then use the MediaRouteSelector in any of your component.

Hope your build.gradle is like this

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.git.demo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Just add the below dependency

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.2.1'
```

}

Comment: I did it guys, i'm using the v23 tho, because when I put v25, it says that the library version cannot exceed the sdk version (my is showing 23)

Comment: @IgorLima plz check the updated answer I have verified it on my local machine

Comment: @IgorLima Welcome